# Postgresql Triggers & Rules not firing for remote inserts

Tags: postgresql, triggers, insert, rule

I've spent all afternoon searching on this problem w/o any luck.

I have tried this with both a Rule and a Trigger and get the same behavior. I can create the Rule or Trigger and test it locally by inserting a record manually into the DB using 'psql' yet when I try to insert a record remotely using a JAVA app, the triggers do not fire.

A simplified example is this:

I have a table "Customer_Address" that has fields:

- customerid
- zipcode
- city
- state

I have tried to create both rules and triggers so that when a new record gets inserted into "Customer_Address" with just a zipcode, my trigger/rule will take the zipcode and using a nested subquery it will query the City & State from a lookup table and then set the City & State fields using the return values from the nested subqueries.

I can get this to work with either a trigger or a rule no problems yet only when I insert the record locally on the DB server using 'psql'.

If I attempt to insert the record remotely using the JAVA App, the record inserts fine yet the trigger nor rule never fires.

I even tried the command  "alter table Customer_Address enable always trigger update_address_trig";

Yet the trigger never fires from the remote insert. Same goes with the a Rule. Since both the Trigger and Rule work fine locally from the psql command line, and since the rest of the fields get inserted from the JAVA App I am fairly sure that I have my Trigger/Rule syntax correct along with remote accessibility to the DB correctly configured, etc. I am even using the same DB user at both the psql command line and through the JAVA App.

I found various solutions to this problem for MS SQL Server yet none for Postgresql.

Anyone have any ideas? Why should a Trigger behave differently from a local vs remote insert?

Thx in advance!

Brig

The trigger code is:

```
create or replace function update_event_stage() returns trigger as 
$$
begin 
  update Event_stage set EventCity = (select primarycity from zipmap where zipcode = Event_stage.Event_ZipCode) where EventCity is null;
  RETURN NEW; 
end 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql; 

create trigger update_event_stage_trig 
AFTER INSERT or UPDATE on event_stage 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_event_stage(); 

alter table Event_stage enable always trigger update_event_stage_trig;
```

******** *(Added final comment 02/26/2014 20:40 PST)****************

OK thanks again but I had seen the debug docs info earlier and added RAISE clauses yet I got no errors hence why I asked where they should go cuz I thought maybe I was using them in the wrong place.

Anyway still no errors, nothing in Firebug, java App inserts to table fine yet no trigger fire. Manual insert with psql fires trigger and updates City based on zipcode lookup as coded.

I will keep hacking at it, I only posted cuz I saw that on other DBs like Oracle & SQl Server there were specific parameters that affected behavior like this and thought maybe Postgres had the same yet maybe was undocumented but I guess not.

Had I not seen the triggers and rules work fine locally I would have suspected my trigger coding was erroneous yet seeing them work as designed locally through psql made me assume this was some other issue than the Trigger coding.

Thx!

Comment: Show your code please - the trigger code, the Java code, and the SQL. Verify you're really connecting to the same database in both cases, and the same table. Look at the logs to see if the trigger might actually be firing and encountering an error. How are you determining that the trigger isn't firing? Are you connecting to Pg as the same user with `psql` and with Java? Also, PostgreSQL version and PgJDBC version please. (BTW, it's "Java" not "JAVA", it isn't an acronym).

Comment: I appreciate your help, yet many of the questions you asked I already answered: Yes I am on the same DB, as I stated the record gets created through java App fine yet the fields that the Trigger/rule are supposed to update do not get updated. I can see both records in the table, one from local insert one from remote. If you insert the record locally trigger/rule fires. Yes Same user (I stated that). Postgres 9.3.2. Nothing in the log files. I am not posting all the code for like I said, it all works when inserting locally through psql no errors, updated the fields correctly, etc. Thx!

Comment: Add a "RAISE ERROR" to the trigger. See if the error is triggers by the Java app.

Comment: Ok I will try. btw here is simplified Trigger code: create or replace function update_event_stage()
returns trigger as
$$

begin

update Event_stage set

EventCity = 
(select primarycity from zipmap where zipcode = Event_stage.Event_ZipCode) 

where EventCity is null;
RETURN NEW;
end
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
 
create trigger update_event_stage_trig
 AFTER INSERT or UPDATE on event_stage
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_event_stage();

alter table Event_stage enable always trigger update_event_stage_trig;

Comment: you can add info as edits to the post, rather than as comments. That way it can be legible. I did it for you. First thing I notice in your trigger is that the `UPDATE` doesn't refer to `OLD` or `NEW` at all; what's it supposed to do, and why is it in an `AFTER` trigger? And what stops the trigger running infinitely recursively? I suspect you actually want a `BEFORE` trigger that modifies the `NEW` record here...

Comment: Thx Craig! Well I have tried every iteration of BEFORE, AFTER, NEW, OLD, etc, etc, tried every example I can find on the Internet. Many do not work yet the one I posted DOES work when I insert a record on the command line using psql. Many other iterations have worked too (many ways to skin a cat) the main thing is that whether I code it as a rule or a trigger, it works "AS DESIGNED" from the psql command line yet not from the java APP, yet the java App does insert the fields it is supposed to insert, just no trigger fire. Can you help with RAISE ERROR syntax? not sure how to code that. Thx!

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html