# How to defer a reading in a table in PostgreSQL until the triggers (which calls Java) of this table end?

Tags: java, postgresql, triggers

- I am provided a PostgreSQL table1 which has blobs in a column. I want to "unblob" this column in several columns in a table2 because my client doesn't want to read blobs and 'decode' them itself. So, he will read the table1 columns which are 'clear' and also the corresponding table2 columns.
- I thought that I could have a trigger in table1 that fires a signal which calls a Java function which does all the decode stuff and inserts a row in table2.
- What if if the client reads table1 while the insertion in table 2 is not yet finished or even not started because the JAVA function is running ?
- Is there a way to defer the reading until the insert (or update) in table2 has ended ?

**Before asking this, I've read the following questions :**

1. [Lock and transaction in postgres that should block a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945742/lock-and-transaction-in-postgres-that-should-block-a-query#22954151)
2. [Postgresql Triggers & Rules not firing for remote inserts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22057682/postgresql-triggers-rules-not-firing-for-remote-inserts)
3. [Postgres DB Trigger calling Java Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614710/postgres-db-trigger-calling-java-function#6615291)

**and the following documentation :**

1. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html
2. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html
3. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/mvcc-intro.html

Comment: How complicated/expensive is this decoding? Maybe you could get away with a view? (And implement that in PL/pgSQL rather then Java)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. the current blob comes from a Java DICOM object. When we want to decode it, we first need to ask postgresql to encode this blob in base64 then feed this base64 to a Java method which creates a structured DICOM Object from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trigger can only be fired from `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` or `TRUNCATE` (we are not talking about DDL triggers here).

So your setup will only work if you want `table2` to be written by a trigger whenever `table1` is modified. In that case nothing can go wrong, because the data modifying statement will run in the same transaction as the trigger, and no data written by a transaction are visible before the transaction commits.

If you want `table2` to be written whenever `table1` is *read*, that won't work. If there are already data in `table1` with no corresponding entries in `table2`, you'll have to create entries in `table2` with a one-time batch process.

I would suggest that you don't use Java if you can avoid it. It is rather heavyweight, and PL/Java is not part of the standard distribution, so it will be more challenging to install. If you need a powerful programming language in a function, use PL/Perl.

Comment: Well. The database is managed by an opensource "big application" who handles the INSERT in table1. At this time, I don't want to modigy the source code but only the schema, so yes, I'd use an TRIGGER whenever there is an INSERT in table1.

Comment: That's fine then. The batch job is only intended to cover the rows that were entered *before* you define the trigger.